# Drupal Email address ends up in Billing not Home

Tags: email, online-registration

I am running CiviCRM 5.13.4, and have the following scenario.

•   Administrator creates an Individual Contact offline, without any email address.
•   The User then registers for an online account through Drupal, which includes entering an email address.
•   The User can then log on as usual.

The system successfully deduplicates with the original contact, using the name and postcode (collected on the registration Profile).
BUT the email entered by the User ends up as the Billing Email Address, not the Home address, and the Billing Email becomes the Primary email, which is not what is wanted.

It looks as if the linkage with Drupal is just picking up the first entry on the list of location types, and not taking note of the Default type which is set to Home.

This is a quite possible scenario when we migrate our existing membership database, and some of them start to use the online capability for the first time.

Is there any fix or workaround?

With thanks, Tony

Comment: Was unable to replicate this on 5.13.4. The email address was set to value set as default in location type.

Comment: Pls specify D7 or D8

Comment: Sorry - Drupal 7.67.

Comment: If one creates an entirely new Contact by Registering a Drupal Account, then the email address ends up up in the (default) Home email on the Contact.  If you create the Contact in CiviCRM first, with no email address, then when a new Drupal Accouint is registered the de-duplication process ends up with the email in Billing.

Comment: A further observation - the email from Drupal Registration shows up on the civiCRM View Cintact screen as Billing, but if you get the details via the API it has no Location Type Id at all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is now fixed as part this [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14489). Can you please try patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14489.patch) if it fixes your problem?

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: It should fix it ... the PR was originally for @maynardsmith's site :-)

Comment: Hi, Yes this sorts my problem - thanks to all.
Can you tell me how I will know when this is included in a regular release of CiviCRM? 
regards, Tony

Comment: It will be part of 5.16

Comment: Thank you.  Regards, Tony